# Doctrine 2 DQL - how to select inverse side of unidirectional many-to-many query?

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

I have two classes - Page and SiteVersion, which have a many to many relationship. Only SiteVersion is aware of the relationship (because the site is modular and I want to be able to take away and drop in the module that SiteVersion belongs to).

How would I therefore select pages based on criteria of SiteVersion?

For example, this doesn't work:

```
SELECT p FROM SiteVersion v JOIN v.pages p WHERE v.id = 5 AND p.slug='index'
```

I get the error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT p FROM': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.
```

Even though I can select "v" with this query.

I think I could possibly resolve this by introducing a class for the relationship (a PageToVersion class) but is there any way without doing that, or making it bidirectional?

Comment: Hey Gnuffo1, Could you please accept @Ocramius's answer, I think there is no doubt this solved your issue.

Answer (score 29):

There's two ways of handling this in Doctrine ORM. The most typical one is using an `IN` condition with a subquery:

```
SELECT
    p
FROM
    SitePage p
WHERE
    p.id IN(
        SELECT
            p2.id
        FROM
            SiteVersion v
        JOIN
            v.pages p2
        WHERE
            v.id = :versionId
            AND
            p.slug = :slug
    )
```

The other way is with an additional join with the [arbitrary join functionality introduced in version 2.3 of the ORM](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples):

```
SELECT
    p
FROM
    SitePage p
JOIN
    SiteVersion v
WITH
    1 = 1
JOIN
    v.pages p2
WHERE
    p.id = p2.id
    AND
    v.id = :versionId
    AND
    p2.slug = :slug
```

The `1 = 1` is just because of a current limitation of the parser.

Please note that [the limitation that causes the semantical error](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1078) is because the hydration process starts from the root of the selected entities. Without a root in place, the hydrator has no reference on how to collapse [fetch-joined](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) or joined results.

Comment: Is this still the best practice for this scenario or is there something for this now in doctrine 2.5?

Comment: Yes, this didn't change.

Comment: Also I would like to know if this impacts performance (the 1=1 part)? Otherwise I would have to look into another solution for this, I have a lot of DQL queries that need to join like this.

Comment: No, decent SQL planners strip the comparison away before executing the query.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to get native queries working, so have resolved in a slightly hacky way:

```
$id = $em->getConnection()->fetchColumn("SELECT
    pages.id
    FROM
    pages
    INNER JOIN siteversion_page ON siteversion_page.page_id = pages.id
    INNER JOIN siteversions ON siteversion_page.siteversion_id = siteversions.id
    WHERE siteversions.id = 1
    AND pages.slug = 'index'");

$page = $em->find('Page', $id);
```

I don't like it because it results in more queries to the database (especially if I need to fetch an array of pages instead of one) but it works.

**Edit**: I've decided to just go with a class for the association. Now I can do this query:

```
SELECT p FROM Page p, SiteVersionPageLink l
WHERE l.page = p AND l.siteVersion = 5 AND p.slug = 'index'
```

Comment: You don't really need the association if this kind of traversing is rare. Yes, it simplifies things, but you get some performance drawbacks when hydrating your objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to select the SiteVersion in your query too:

```
SELECT v, p FROM SiteVersion v JOIN v.pages p WHERE v.id = 5 AND p.slug='index'
```

You will get an array of SiteVersion entities which you can loop through to get the Page entities.

Comment: This will fetch-join the site pages into the site versions, returning a list of `SiteVersion` objects, and not just the site pages. This is actually wrong given the expected resultset (as of the question).

Answer (score 1):

Try this (or something like it):

```
SELECT p FROM Page p WHERE EXISTS (SELECT v FROM SiteVersion v WHERE p MEMBER OF v.pages AND v.id = 5 AND p.slug = 'index')
```

I haven't tested this exactly, but I have gotten something similar to work.  The use of `EXISTS` and `MEMBER OF` are buried in the [DQL Select Examples](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) section of the DQL chapter.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution for this problem [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1001).

According to that page, your query should look something like this:

`SELECT p FROM SiteVersion v, Page p WHERE v.id = 5 AND p.slug='index' AND v.page = p;`

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: No. The problem is, it's a many-to-many, not one-to-many. It's v.pages, not v.page but even if I do: "SELECT p FROM SiteVersion v, Page p WHERE v.id = 5 AND p.slug='index' AND v.pages = p" that doesn't work either (Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.)

Comment: Then why not you specify the other side of the relationship in your schema definition?

Comment: Because I want to be able to just drop this module in without affecting anything that's already there.

Comment: Is using native sql to select at least the page id-s is a viable option for you? Of course it would be much cleaner to use DQL...