# Doctrine2 manyToMany Inverse QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities

`Product`and `Category`

`Product` has a `manyToMany` (unidirectional) field with `Category` with a jointable named `product_has_category`

I can find easily which `Category` has any `Product`but I don't know how to get the inverse...

Let's say I want to get all `Product` for a certain `Category` in a form, that form's field is `category` so I can't get an entity field type with `Product` query, otherwise it will fail.

```
$form
    ->add('category', 'entity', array(
        'class'     => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
        'property'  => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $em) use ($product) {
            return $em
                ->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->innerJoin('AppBundle\Entity\Product', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.id = :product_id')
                ->setParameter('product_id', $product->getId())
                ;
        },
        'multiple'  => true
    ))
;
```

Of course this doesn't work, but you get the idea of what I want to do. As `Category` doesn't have any mapped field with `Product` (because it is an unidirectional mapping), I can't find easy thoose products...

The middle table doesn't has an entity, because we don't need it, it's just a mysql table.

Running a MySQL query would be this easy, but we need it to be inside a QueryBuilder because we will use it in forms.

```
SELECT c.name 
FROM category c
INNER JOIN product_has_category pc ON pc.category_id = e.id
INNER JOIN product p ON pc.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 10
;
```

This, of course returns me exactly what I want, because on MySQL I do have access to the middle table so I can join everything.. but, QueryBuilder? I don't know

I've tried this but I just got everything freezed (over 7M records fetched I guess)

```
$em
->createQueryBuilder('c')
->select('c')
->innerJoin('AppBundle\Entity\Product', 'p', 'WITH', '1 = 1')
->innerJoin('p.categories', 'c')
->where('p.id = :product_id')
->setParameter('product_id', $product->getId())
;
```

I think it is not duplicated because other question doesn't include a `QueryBuilder` solution/question, and some people may be confused about how to do so.

Comment: You can use "arbitrary join" http://stackoverflow.com/a/15444719

Comment: @jkavalik But how can I do that in a QueryBuilder? Because that is a raw query.

Comment: In your code `p.id = :product_id` should be in `where()`, the `WITH` keyword in DQL is the equivalent of the `ON` from SQL join. Otherwise the QB is just a tool to help you build the query dynamically but it uses all the same features and syntax. You can just take Ocramius' second example and rewrite it directly (or test it with dql beforehand - imho you should only use QB for dynamic queries, anything else is much shorter and more readable as DQL)

Comment: I did that and I just got my computer freezed because I have over 7 million products, and everything exploded... This is my QB (see updated question)

Comment: you are using `c` as alias twice and missing the part of the `where` condition which joins `c1` with `c2`. When doing such things, use $qb->getSQL() to see the query it creates before you run it (it has getDQL() method too to check that one).

Comment: Okay thanks, that seems to work. Please create an answer in order to approve it if you want, otherwise I will put my code as answer in case someone needs the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 DQL - how to select inverse side of unidirectional many-to-many query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432404/doctrine-2-dql-how-to-select-inverse-side-of-unidirectional-many-to-many-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For thoose who ants to know how to do it inside QueryBuilder, thanks to @jkavalik answer referencing other question

[Doctrine 2 DQL - how to select inverse side of unidirectional many-to-many query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432404/doctrine-2-dql-how-to-select-inverse-side-of-unidirectional-many-to-many-query)

This is the code I've used which is working like a charm.

```
$form
    ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
        'class'     => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
        'property'  => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $em) use ($product) {
            return $em
                ->createQueryBuilder('c1')
                ->innerJoin('AppBundle\Entity\Product', 'p', 'WITH', '1 = 1')
                ->innerJoin('p.equipments', 'c2')
                ->where('p.id = :product_id')
                ->andWhere('c1.id = c2.id')
                ->setParameter('product_id', $product->getId())
            ;
        }
    ))
;
```